# How do I insert '][' in between the two patterns with sed?

Tags: regex, sed, markdown, regex-group

I wrote a Bash script that utilizes regular expressions in order
to process my text files written in markdown so that they can be ready to be compiled to .html files. One task of this processing is meant to
change lazily written text that looks like this:

> Verkle trees are shaping up to be an important part of Ethereum's upcoming scaling upgrades.
> They serve the same function as Merkle trees: [you can put a large amount of data into a Verkle tree3],
> and make a short proof ("witness") of any single piece, or set of pieces, of that data that can be verified by
> someone who only has the root of the tree.

into text that when compiled will display a link:

> Verkle trees are shaping up to be an important part of Ethereum's upcoming scaling upgrades.
> They serve the same function as Merkle trees: [you can put a large amount of data into a Verkle tree][3],
> and make a short proof ("witness") of any single piece, or set of pieces, of that data that can be verified by
> someone who only has the root of the tree.

In other words, I want to replace `[text that begins with a letter and consists of words, letters and punctuation. The text ends with a positive integer smaller than 100 int]` with `[text that begins with a letter and consists of words, letters and punctuation.The text ends with a bracket][int]`

The following is the code snipped that is meant to do the task that I described above:

```
sed -i -E 's/(\[[a-zA-Z]{2,2}[\s\S]{1,100})(\[0-9]{1,2}\])/\1\][\2/g' file.txt;
```

The code is meant to save me from the effort writing additional '][' and will do it for me automatically. The code does not work and I have no clue why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you wrote is [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)-compliant, but you need a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) one since `sed` only support POSIX BRE or ERE.

You can use

```sh
sed -i -E 's/(\[[[:alpha:]]{2}([^][]*[^0-9])?)([0-9]{1,2}])/\1][\3/g' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/L12ugW):

```sh
s='Verkle trees are shaping up to be an important part of Ethereum'"'"'s upcoming scaling upgrades. They serve the same function as Merkle trees: [you can put a large amount of data into a Verkle tree3], and make a short proof ("witness") of any single piece, or set of pieces, of that data that can be verified by someone who only has the root of the tree.'
sed -E 's/(\[[[:alpha:]]{2}([^][]*[^0-9])?)([0-9]{1,2}])/\1][\3/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```sh
Verkle trees are shaping up to be an important part of Ethereum's upcoming scaling upgrades. They serve the same function as Merkle trees: [you can put a large amount of data into a Verkle tree][3], and make a short proof ("witness") of any single piece, or set of pieces, of that data that can be verified by someone who only has the root of the tree.
```

*Details*:

- `(\[[[:alpha:]]{2}([^][]*[^0-9])?)` - Group 1 (`\1`):

  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `[[:alpha:]]{2}` - two letters
  - `([^][]*[^0-9])?` - an optional sequence of zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a non-digit char
- `([0-9]{1,2}])` - Group 3 (`\3`): one or two digits.

The replacement is `\1][\3`, Group 1 + `][` + Group 3 values concatenated (Group 2 is not used as it is only meant to match an optional part inside Group 1, and `sed`, POSIX, regex flavor does not support non-capturing groups).

Comment: Thank you - it works. The script is more complex than what I asked for in my question. It also handles references placed at the bottom of the file so that one can write them lazily, like so; `1url`. Let me paste it here for the benefit of everyone: `find /home/jerzy/ -type f -mmin -30 -iname "*.html.pmd" -execdir /usr/bin/sed -i -E 's/(\[[a-zA-Z]{2}([^][]*[^0-9])?)([0-9]{1,2}])/\1][\3/g;;s/(^[0-9]{1,2})(http)/\[\1\]: \2/g' {} \; `

Comment: @JerzyBrzóska Ok, we can only answer what was asked, glad it worked in your code.